# Sql Server - Conversão de Hora (HH:mm) para Decimal

Tags: sql, banco-de-dados, sql-server, data, decimal

Olá, estou trabalhando em um sistema que requer conversão de horas em decimal e está apresentando erro de conversão de HORA (HH:mm) para decimal quando o total de horas ultrapassa 23:59.

Para melhor entendimento se eu tento converter para decimal a HORA '23:59' não ocorre erro, porém se eu tento converter '60:59' ocorre o erro 'The conversion of a varchar data type to a datetime data type resulted in an out-of-range value.'

Qual seria a forma ideal para que um total de horas:minutos maior ou igual a 24:00 sejam convertidos corretamente para decimal?

```sql
DECLARE @HorasAtendidas VARCHAR(5) = '23:59', --Se mudar para 60:59 ocorre o erro citado.
@CargaHoraria DECIMAL(18, 2)


SET @CargaHoraria = (
SELECT
                CONVERT(NUMERIC(18,4),ROUND(DATEDIFF(ms, 0, 
                    RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CONVERT(INT, LEFT(@HorasAtendidas, 2))) + (((SUM(CONVERT (INT, RIGHT (@HorasAtendidas, 2)))) - (SUM(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@HorasAtendidas, 2))) % 60)) / 60)), 2) + ':' +  
                        RIGHT('0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(CONVERT(INT, RIGHT(@HorasAtendidas, 2))) % 60), 2)     
                ) / 3600000.000000, 4))
                )

select @CargaHoraria
```

Obrigado desde já.

Comment: Preciso converter um total de horas para decimal e esse total pode ultrapassar 24:00.

Comment: Imagine o cenário, faço uma consultoria de 60 horas e 30 minutos para meu cliente (60:30). No banco de dados a carga horária deverá ser armazenada em decimal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Richard, segue uma sugestão para testes, verifique se são obtidos os resultados esperados:

```
DECLARE 
  @HorasAtendidas VARCHAR(5) = '60:59',
  @HorasAtendidasInt int,
  @CargaHoraria DECIMAL(18, 2);

SET @HorasAtendidasInt = CONVERT(INT, REPLACE(@HorasAtendidas, ':', ''));
SET @CargaHoraria = @HorasAtendidasInt / 100 + @HorasAtendidasInt % 100 / 60.0;

select @CargaHoraria
```

Espero que ajude

Comment: Muito obrigado! Sua sugestão deu certo! Era isso mesmo!! Você é o cara!